# SQL Server 2017 Express offline installer

Tags: sql-server, installation, offline

Is there a offline installer for SQL Server 2017 Express?

I have very slow internet in my home, so I want to download on my office computer an offline installer, put it on an USB stick & install in on my home computer.

Comment: The response to the duplicate I marked is for SQL Server 2016 - but it works for 2017, too - there's a very prominent "Download Media" option on the main screen when you launch the installer

Comment: Thanks you, that answer is for localdb, So it didn't came up in my search, But I can use it also for expres

Comment: The suggested duplicate does not match the question.

Comment: hi, you can get full offline installer from https://my.visualstudio.com/downloads